# MySQL - Multiple INNER JOIN, CONCAT and UNION ALL - How to order from different tables/columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following query with multiple `INNER JOINS`,`CONCAT` with `UNION ALL` statements.

How would I add some `ORDER BY` statements for different tables and columns in this query?

For example `ORDER BY unit.unit_name ASC, learning_event.learning_event_name ASC, assessment.assessment ASC`

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yWHFAS7jRizh29ZGBd8Ve/0)

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
           p.program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_group:', pg.program_group_pk) AS global_id,
           pg.program_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program:', pg.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_group pg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_group:', pog.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog.program_outcome_group) AS global_id,
           pog.program_outcome_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog.program_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome_group pog
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog2.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog2.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po.program_outcome) AS global_id,
           po.program_outcome AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog2.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog2.program_outcome_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome po
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON po.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u.unit_full_name) AS global_id,
           u.unit_full_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit u
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po2 ON po2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog3 ON po2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog3.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug.unit_group) AS global_id,
           ug.unit_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog3.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog3.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit_group ug
    INNER JOIN unit u2 ON u2.unit_pk = ug.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po2 ON po2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog3 ON po2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog3.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group,  ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = le.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u3.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po3 ON po3.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog4 ON po3.program_outcome_group_fk = pog4.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN learning_event_program_outcome_lookup lepol 
    ON lepol.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk 
    AND lepol.program_outcome_fk = po3.program_outcome_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group,  ',assessment:', t1.assessment) AS global_id,
           t1.assessment AS name,
           CONCAT('program_group:', pog4.program_group_fk, 'program_outcome_group:', pog4.program_outcome_group, ',program_outcome:', po3.program_outcome, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id
    FROM assessment t1
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = t1.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u3.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome po3 ON po3.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog4 ON po3.program_outcome_group_fk = pog4.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN assessment_program_outcome_lookup t5 
    ON t5.assessment_fk = t1.assessment_pk 
    AND t5.program_outcome_fk = po3.program_outcome_pk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `ORDER BY`/`LIMIT` in `UNION [ALL]` the `SELECT` needs to be in parentesis.

e.g:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

ref: [mysql manual on union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-order-by-limit) / [mariadb kb on union](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/union/#order-by-and-limit)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that in the above fiddle and not working.  Could you show this working in the above fiddle?

Comment: like [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yWHFAS7jRizh29ZGBd8Ve/1)? So each query section needed to include only the `order by` that was in that section. Also with table aliases you need to use those rather than the original table names.

Comment: Looks good, thanks, let me test a bit....and I will get back.